AMD Radeon Drivers Crash with Error 43 when I connect HDMI to 3D Projector EH-LS500B
When I connect my windows 11 PC to my EH-LS500B 3D capable projector the AMD Radeon drivers crash with Error 43.
The only way to recover the issue is to disconnect the HDMI cable and then goto Device Manager and disable the AMD Radeon Graphics device, wait a minute or two then enable it again.
When I plug in the HDMI cable the projector appears to be receiving video but the window shows in the top corner and the rest of the screen is black and it flickers for about 30 seconds before it fails back to VGA resolution and tells me the AMD Radeon Drivers had error code 43.

The cause of the problem was that Windows was setting the Active Resolution to 4K even though the selected resolution was 1080p. Since "3D Mode" was turned on from display settings it was trying to enter frame packed 3d mode but also trying to output a 4K resolution and getting confused before crashing the video drivers.
The only way to recover the issue was to

Use ToastyX CRU tool, to remove all 4K resolutions from the HDMI port for the projector.
Connect the HDMI and actually have to engage frame packed 3D at 1080P instead of confusing itself with active resolution 4K.
Disable "3D Mode" from display settings.
Use ToastyX reset all to revert the default EDID for the projector, then restart64. (It will now be on the 4k resolution again but since 3d isn't enabled any more it will work and the drivers won't crash with error code 43)
NOW if you want to use "3D Mode" goto the display settings -> detailed settings and manually force it to use 1080P (so that windows wouldn't try and use active resolution 4k when in 3d mode and blow up)
Finally re-enabled "3D Mode" and confirm the "active resolution" is still 1080p and not 4K.

Hopefully this will help someone, as I spent nearly 2 hours repeatedly re-installing drivers only to have them blow up every time I connected my projectors HDMI.
